# How to set window to be always on top of any window, not just its owner in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

My application has two stages, each of them opens in full screen on a separate monitor. Each stage has several controls (buttons etc). Each control, when activated, opens a small additional window. For each window, I initialize the owner to the stage it was called from, so it always stays on top of its owner stage. But if I drag an additional window to second screen and then try to activate the control on second screen, then the dragged window disappears behind the second screen stage. I don't want to init window's modality, for I need to be able to open multiple additional windows.

I've tried to set each spawned additional window to be always on top, but this approach didn't work as expected, and more this creates problems with dragging windows, since the most recently opened windows will always be on top of other windows, regardless of focus.
I'm expecting these additional windows to be always on top of two full screen stages, but not on top of any windows, that are spawned but fullscreen stages (more precisely, I want them to behave as if they are on their home screen, even when dragged to another screen). As if I set multiple owner windows for each additional window